# MySQL double value out of range

Tags: mysql

The problem here is obvious, I have a value of `0.0000000000005950183389581887` which is too large to fit into a DOUBLE column using MySQL 5.6.

My question is, what data type should the column be or what can I alter this column to in order to be able to store a number with that precision?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [DECIMAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fixed-point-types.html). For instance

```
DECIMAL(50,30)
```

where `50` is the total number of decimal places and `30` the number of decimal places after the point.