# DOUBLE value is out of range

Tags: mysql

I am getting the error "DOUBLE value is out of range," but the suggested answers don't seem to work.

The equation is:

`select 144254*8.524789415648847e307;`

I am going to guess that this is just a limitation of MySQL. The answer should be:

12297349723650088420210958255312752983226655887341313892168288956573735751743741397634413196477674817934705029300600187860424954067080731983114901902495162280851999670265668298743275405871711207842259780845007110767808685197279959365690523810797428906456118395209507549026477413087458372311414663408660706125414400

Basically, I am creating a clicker game entirely in MySQL. I know that this is a terrible idea, I just ran with it to learn as much about MySQL as I can. It has taught me a lot about its limitations. Just one example, I had to change each column's datatype to LONGTEXT in order to handle the length of some variables.

You can check out my project here: https://github.com/GarinJTanner/CLICK

Conveniently enough, the game breaks right after you hit Centillionaire, the last title given in the game.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL double value out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22919515/mysql-double-value-out-of-range)

Comment: "I am going to guess that this is just a limitation of MySQL" - yeah, as the error message tells you. Which suggested answers are you talking about?

Comment: I was told CAST was one of the resolutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I never specified the variable to be double.

The value 8.524789415648847e307 is a `DOUBLE` value. No other data type in MySQL can represent that numeric value (you could store a string with those characters, but that isn't a numeric value, and you can't do math on it).

Since you have a `DOUBLE` in your expression, the result of the expression is also `DOUBLE`. This is due to MySQL's implicit type conversion that happens in expressions.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html says:

> If one of the arguments is a decimal value, comparison depends on the other argument. The arguments are compared as decimal values if the other argument is a decimal or integer value, or as floating-point values if the other argument is a floating-point value.

But the value resulting from your expression is too large to be represented by an IEEE `DOUBLE` or any other data type in MySQL.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-syntax.html says:

> `DOUBLE[(M,D)] [UNSIGNED] [ZEROFILL]`
>
> A normal-size (double-precision) floating-point number. Permissible
> values are -1.7976931348623157E+308 to -2.2250738585072014E-308, 0,
> and 2.2250738585072014E-308 to 1.7976931348623157E+308. These are the
> theoretical limits, based on the IEEE standard. The actual range might
> be slightly smaller depending on your hardware or operating system.

MySQL does not implement a solution for unlimited precision math.

It won't help to use CAST() to convert these values to a string, because MySQL can't do math on a string. It would have to evaluate your numeric expression before casting to string, and it can't do that because of the overflow.

Answer (score -1):

The issue here, is that you are trying to store the result in a double.

But the problem is that a double have a maximum value of 1.7976931348623157E+308

Source :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.maxvalue?view=net-7.0

Considering that you are actually multiplying by more than 10 you are reaching a higher value than the maximum allowed.

Thus your error problem.

It is not espicially related to mySQL it is related to the variable format.

I would suggest you to have a look at other types of variable if you want to store such a huge value.
But it might not be easy.

Double is the variable type meant for big numbers so finding another might be hard

Hope it helped you,

Have a goood day !

Comment: Perhaps, but I never specified the variable to be double. The other number is so large it automatically truncates to scientific notation. Perhaps if I can undo scientific notation?

Comment: What makes you think that the definition of `DOUBLE` from .NET applies to MySQL?

Comment: "it is related to the variable format" - what does that mean? Which other format would allow storing such a large number in a double?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).